# How would I go about sending the pdf output of pdfLaTeX to a discord channel right after compiling it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is what I've tried so far, although it does not manage to send the pdf, it only compiles the TeX code that's been given to it. I'm quite new to python so please bear with me if the answer to my question seems fairly obvious.

```py
import os
import discord
import subprocess

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

allowed_IDs = [1234567890]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")

@bot.command()
async def tex(ctx, *, code):
    if ctx.author.id in allowed_IDs:
        await subprocess.call(f"pdflatex -output-directory=tex -jobname={ctx.author.id} -interaction=nonstopmode -no-shell-escape tex/default.tex '\\begin{{document}}{code}\\end{{document}}'")
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f"tex/{ctx.author.id}.pdf"))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You cannot use this command")

bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: `subprocess.call` is not a coroutine, why are you awaiting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On @Łukasz Kwieciński's advice, I removed `await` from `subprocess.call`, and it turns out that this is why my code was not working as intended. Thank you so much for your help.